# Groupby to compare, identify, and make notes on max date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, grouped-table

I am working with the following table:

```
+------+------+------+------+---------------+---------+-------+
| ID 1 | ID 2 | Date | Type | Marked_Latest | Updated | Notes |
+------+------+------+------+---------------+---------+-------+
|    1 |  100 | 2001 | SMT  |               |         |       |
|    1 |  101 | 2005 | SMT  |               |         |       |
|    1 |  102 | 2020 | SMT  | Latest        |         |       |
|    1 |  103 | 2020 | SMT  |               |         |       |
|    1 |  103 | 2020 | ABT  |               |         |       |
|    2 |  201 | 2009 | CMT  | Latest        |         |       |
|    2 |  202 | 2022 | SMT  |               |         |       |
|    2 |  203 | 2022 | SMT  |               |         |       |
+------+------+------+------+---------------+---------+-------+
```

I am trying to perform the following steps using a `df.query()` but since there are so many caveats I am not sure how to fit them all in.

Step 1: Only looking at `Type == "SMT" or Type == "CMT"`, group by ID 1 and identify latest `date`, compare this (grouped ID 1 data) to `date` of `Marked_Latest == "Latest` (essentially, just verifying that the date is correct)

Step 2: If the `date` values are the same, do nothing. If different, then supply `ID 2` next to original `Marked_Latest == "Latest"` in `Updated`

Step 3: If multiple `Latest` have the same max `Date`, put a note in `Notes` that says "multiple".

This will result in the following table:

```
+------+------+------+------+---------------+---------+----------+
| ID 1 | ID 2 | Date | Type | Marked_Latest | Updated |  Notes   |
+------+------+------+------+---------------+---------+----------+
|    1 |  100 | 2001 | SMT  |               |         |          |
|    1 |  101 | 2005 | SMT  |               |         |          |
|    1 |  102 | 2020 | SMT  | Latest        |         | multiple |
|    1 |  103 | 2020 | SMT  |               |         | multiple |
|    1 |  103 | 2020 | ABT  |               |         |          |
|    2 |  201 | 2009 | CMT  | Latest        |     203 |          |
|    2 |  202 | 2022 | SMT  |               |         | multiple |
|    2 |  203 | 2022 | SMT  |               |         | multiple |
+------+------+------+------+---------------+---------+----------+
```

To summarize: check that the latest date is actually marked as latest date. If it is not marked as latest date, write the updated `ID 2` next to the original (incorrect) latest date. And when there are multiple cases of latest date, inputting "multiple" for each ID of latest date.

I have gotten only as far as identifying the actual latest date, using

```
q = df.query('Type' == "SMT" or 'Type' == "CMT").groupby('ID 1').last('ID 2')
q
```

This will return a subset with the latest dates marked, but I am not sure how to proceed from here, i.e. how to now compare this dataframe with the `date` field corresponding to `Marked_Latest`.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So we placed the `ID 2` of the actual latest in the column next to it. "Actual latest" is a bit convoluted because of replicating years, but we can assume any of the `ID 2` in the max year can be the actual latest.

Comment: Why 203 and not 202? The dates are the same.

Comment: It can really be either. I tried this a few minutes ago and I am not sure how pandas return max `ID 2` when the dates are the same. It seems to be random but in my example it is really whatever the default max found by pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cols = ['ID 1', 'ID 2', 'Date', 'Type', 'Marked_Latest', 'Updated', 'Notes']

data = [[1, 100, 2001, 'SMT', '', '', ''],
      [1, 101, 2005, 'SMT', '', '', ''],
      [1, 102, 2020, 'SMT', 'Latest', '', ''],
      [1, 103, 2020, 'SMT', '', '', ''],
      [1, 103, 2020, 'ABT', '', '', '']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
temp = df[(df['Type'] == "SMT")|(df['Type'] == "CMT")]
new = temp.groupby('ID 1')['ID 2'].last().values[0]
latest = temp[temp['Marked_Latest'] == 'Latest']
nind = temp[temp['ID 2'] == new].index

if new != latest['ID 2'].values[0]:
    df.loc[latest.index,'Updated']=new
    df.loc[latest.index, 'Notes'] = 'multiple'
    df.loc[nind, 'Notes'] = 'multiple'
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#ID from ID 1 only if match conditions
df['ID'] = df['ID 1'].where(df['Type'].isin(['SMT','CMT']))
#get last Date, ID 2 per `ID` to columns Notes, Updates
df[['Notes', 'Updated']] = df.groupby('ID')[['Date', 'ID 2']].transform('last')

#comapre latest date in Notes with original Date
m1 = df['Notes'].ne(df['Date'])

#if no match set empty string
df['Updated'] = df['Updated'].where(m1 & df['Marked_Latest'].eq('Latest'), '')
#if latest date is duplicated set value multiple
df['Notes'] = np.where(df.duplicated(['ID 1','Date'], keep=False) & ~m1, 'multiple','')

df = df.drop('ID', axis=1)
print (df)
   ID 1  ID 2  Date Type Marked_Latest Updated     Notes
0     1   100  2001  SMT           NaN                  
1     1   101  2005  SMT           NaN                  
2     1   102  2020  SMT        Latest          multiple
3     1   103  2020  SMT           NaN          multiple
4     1   103  2020  ABT           NaN                  
5     2   201  2009  CMT        Latest   203.0          
6     2   202  2022  SMT           NaN          multiple
7     2   203  2022  SMT           NaN          multiple
```